# Making dynamically created Gridview columns read only

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, entity-framework-5

```
 var a = from employee in entities.Employees
         from ticket in employee.EmployeeTicket
         select new {ID=employee.ID,Name=employee.Name,TicketNo=ticket.TicketNo,
         Subject=ticket.Subject,Date=ticket.Date,State=ticket.State.Name};//Columns

GridViewTicketHistory.DataSource = a;//Datasource is Linq to entity
GridViewTicketHistory.DataBind();
```

Gridview has **Linq to entity** data source.
I want to make those **dynamically** created columns(ID,Name,TicketNo,Subject,Date,State) **read only**..I tried to cast using column index  GridViewTicketHistory.Columns[2] to databound in rowdatabound event then making it **read only**.However index is out of range which means it doesnt see any column with that index.Is there any way to choosing specific   column and make it **read only**.If i need to use datatable how can i do it for linq to entity?

Comment: Do you need to use a.ToList() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID"/>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"/>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketNo" HeaderText="TicketNo"/>
   <asp:BoundField DataField=" Subject" HeaderText="Subject"/>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date"/>
 <asp:BoundField DataField="StateName" HeaderText="StateName"/>
```

Dont give names like ID=employee.ID .Thus

```
select new {ID=employee.ID,Name=employee.Name,TicketNo=ticket.TicketNo,
         Subject=ticket.Subject,Date=ticket.Date,State=ticket.State.Name};
```

Becomes ;

```
     select new{employee.ID,employee.Name,ticket.TicketNo,ticket.Subject,
ticket.Date,ticket.State.StateName};
```

Also it wont compile if last variable is same.. employee.Name and ticket.State.Name rename table column in database and recreate entity model.I did it and changed the foreign key column as StateName.Now you can make your databoundfield column read only.
 `((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[0]).ReadOnly = true;` makes ID column read only...